# Django (pre1.7) management command to run the customsql for an app

Tags: python, sql, django, django-south, database-migration

Django (pre 1.7 and pre-the new migration functionality), has a management command `sqlcustom` to *display* the custom SQL that would be run for an app. However that prints it to the terminal. Is there any single django management command to actually *run* all the migrations?

I'm using a Django pre1.7 project which uses South for migrations, and we have some custom SQL (for sql views), and I want to have all the database stuff done via migrations. Custom SQL is loaded by `syncdb` on vanilla Django, but when you use South, it overrides `syncdb` and doesn't run custom sql. I'd like to create a South migration for an app that is really simple and calls this management command to load the custom SQL. (You can [call django management commands from inside python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)). I don't want to duplicate the SQL inside the migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of [`sqlcustom`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlcustom-app-label-app-label) to [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell). Something like this:

```
django-admin.py sqlcustom myapp > django-admin.py dbshell
```